# How to sovle the problem with permissionError(13, 'Permission denied')? I am already run this command as a administrator

Tags: tensorflow, keras, anaconda

I want to install keras in tensorflow, but fail with the permissionerror

> Executing transaction: failed ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(507): An
>   error occurred while installing package
>   'defaults::numpy-base-1.15.4-py36hc3f5095_0'. PermissionError(13,
>   'Permission denied') Attempting to roll back.
>
> Rolling back transaction: done
>
> PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied')

I just run below command:

```
conda install keras
```

Comment: Try this https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/keras

Answer (score 0):

Permission Denied, is probably because you are not running your command as root. Try and run your command as SuperAdmin instead `sudo conda install keras`

Comment: I use the win system, so I open anaconda prompt as administrator, and it still don't work, T T .thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

TensorFlow already contains keras.

Keras switched to `tensorflow.keras`, which is a part of tensorflow>=1.10.0.

Comment: you'r right, I upgrade my tensorflow, it helps! thanks a lot~